Listings inside TikZ nodes
I have been using listings inside TikZ pictures for a long time. Since an update to TeXlive 2024, this stopped working. I cannot pinpoint it to the exact versions of TikZ/listings unfortunately, but in TeXlive 2023, the following example worked:
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node {\lstinputlisting{test.java}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

with test.java just containing abc. With TeXlive 2024, it gives me
Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.6         \node {\lstinputlisting{test.java}}
                                               ;
Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont!

I understand that the semicolon is not parsed correctly and TikZ cannot close the path, but I do not know how to solve this problem. I am using pdftex.

It works if you specify a text width, e.g. \node[text width=5cm] {\lstinputlisting{test.java}};

Wow, that was quick. Thanks, works like a charm!

Welcome to TeX.SX!

The change should be quite new, because in Overleaf TeXLive 2024 it works...

You can avoid the problem by setting a specific line width for the node:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[text width=5cm] {\lstinputlisting{test.java}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

